# Populate a TreeView according to a certain column item

Tags: vb.net

I have this DataSet called "Products" and it is structured like this :

```
ProductID  ProductGroup  ProductName
1          Drinks        Water
2          Other         Fries1
3          Other         Fries2
4          Other         Fries3
```

I want to populate my TreeView in such a way that a Node is created for each ProductGroup (not repetetive) and the ProductName on that Row added to the created Node.

Any clues ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _dt As DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _dt = New DataTable
        _dt.Columns.Add("ProductID", GetType(Integer))
        _dt.Columns.Add("ProductGroup", GetType(String))
        _dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", GetType(String))
        _dt.Rows.Add(1, "Drinks", "Water")
        _dt.Rows.Add(2, "Other", "Fries1")
        _dt.Rows.Add(3, "Other", "Fries2")
        _dt.Rows.Add(4, "Other", "Fries3")

        'Note: Casting can be removed if using a typed datatable

        'Create a root node for each product group, using the product group as the node's key
        Dim ProductGroups = (From rw In _dt Select CType(rw("ProductGroup"), String) Distinct).ToArray

        For Each grp In ProductGroups
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(grp, grp)
        Next

        'Add each product to the appropriate node
        For Each rw In _dt.Rows
            TreeView1.Nodes(CType(rw("ProductGroup"), String)).Nodes.Add(CType(rw("ProductName"), String))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get a NullRefrence exception on the CType line.